# Calling XSLT from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, xslt

I have a series of XML files which reference XSLT files to render as HTML in the browser. Some of these have links which would, on a regular page, perform an AJAX call to request HTML and insert it into a DIV already on the page.

What I want to do is call a webservice from this page, upon a link click, and receive XML which then is processed into HTML in just the same way as the original page was, and then inserted via AJAX into a DIV on the current page.

My question is: How would I get the XML which is downloaded by Javascript to be parsed by it's associated XSLT using Javascript?

Comment: What I'm asking is how to do step #2 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655868/xml-xslt-and-javascript/5650610#5650610
The problem is that this XML is loaded via Javascript.

Comment: I think this is along the lines of what I want to do, though any suggestions would be fanatic, other resources etc... http://learn-ajax-tutorial.com/Xslt.cfm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MSIE you can call `xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc)`. (Both `xmlDoc` and `xslDoc` are XML document objects, as may be loaded through e.g. XHR). In Opera, Firefox etc. you should construct an `XSLTProcessor` first (let's call it `proc`), then call `proc.importStylesheet(xslDoc)`, and finally you can use on of the `transformToXXX` methods of `XSLTProcessor`. (E.g.: `proc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document)` to create  a DOMDocumentFragment which may be inserted in the `document` object using an appropriate `appendChild()` call.)