# Convert Content MathML to infix/math notation string in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, mathjax, mathml, infix-notation

How do I convert Content MathML (example below), in to an infix or math notation string. For example converting this:

```
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <apply>
          <times/>
          <ci> compartment </ci>
          <ci> k1 </ci>
          <ci> S1 </ci>
          <ci> S2 </ci>
        </apply>
      </math>
```

into: `compartment*k1*S1*S2`

I have looked at MathJax, but they do not appear to support Content MathML nor conversion to infix strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several XSLT files around the web which turn content MathML into presentation MathML. One “official” example is [this file](http://www.w3.org/Math/XSL/ctop.xsl) written by David Carlisle. Perhaps you can take that as the basis and adjust it to generate plain text instead of cMathML. You would need to [call XSLT from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7677145/1468366).